# How to properly export two classes on a single index.js file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have two different classes:

**Class1.js**

```
class Class1 { 
    initialize = () => {
        console.log("Class1 Initializer");
    }
}

export default Class1;
```

**Class2.js**

```
class Class2 { 
    initialize = () => {
        console.log("Class2 Initializer");
    }
}

export default Class2;
```

**classes/index.js**

```
import Class1 from "./Class1";
import Class2 from "./Class2";

export default { 
    Class1,
    Class2
}
```

Then I'm trying to use the classes:

**server.js**

```
import { Class1, Class2 } from "./classes";

...
Class1.initialize() <<<<==== ERROR - Cannot read property `initialize` of undefined.
```

What is the correct syntax of the imports and exports? Why is that error happening?

Comment: `initialize = () => {` is class field syntax - it'll be a property of an instance, not of the class itself (if you want a function to be a property of the class itself, use a static method instead). There's also a circular dependency causing issues

Comment: You are default-exporting an object literal. Don't do that - it doesn't match your import statement either. Declare two named exports.

Comment: @OriDrori Why did you delete your answer? It was the correct one

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is, your method of exporting is possible and that this problem is caused by `initialize()` being an instance method of `Class1`.  You'll need to create an instance of `Class1` before calling `initialize()`. One way to instantiate `Class1` would be via `new`:

```
import { Class1, Class2 } from "./classes";

// Create "new" instance of Class1, and then call initialize() on it
(new Class1()).initialize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple things here.

First, you're using arrow syntax in your class methods. Arrow functions don't bind to their own "this" the same way that normal functions do.  I'd recommend refactoring that code to mirror below.  Do the same for both Class1 and Class2.

```
class Class1 {
    initialize() {
        console.log("Class1 Initializer");
    }
}
```

Two, if you're using the ES6 export syntax, you can only ever have one default. In your index.js file, you'll want to just to export { Class1, Class2}, but you can't use export default { Class1, Class2 }.

Three, you need to create an instance of the class before you can call its method.  You can either create a new variable that initializes a new instance of the class, then call the method, or you can do it all in-line.

```
new Class2().initialize();
```

Fourth, you're importing from a file called a file called "./classes".  As far as I can tell that doesn't exist.  It should be from "./index".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are using default on object literal. You cant do that.

Do below in classes/index.js:

```
import Class1 from "./Class1";
import Class2 from "./Class2";

export { 
    Class1,
    Class2
}
```

and then use :

```
import * as Classes from "./classes";
```

Then :

```
new Classes .Class2().initialize();
```

By the way how are running above example? its like **node server.js??** Node 8.5.0 + supports ES6 like import and export style and file extension also should be **.mjs** otherwise .js file will need to use **require** function